# Using $ceil to define a parameter in SystemVerilog in Quartus Prime

Tags: system-verilog, quartus, ceil

Trying to do this

```
parameter integer PRECHARGE_CLOCKS = $ceil(PRECHARGE_NS / CLOCK_PERIOD_NS);
```

And then use the value in a comparion

```
if(InitPrechargeCounter < PRECHARGE_CLOCKS - 1)
```

But getting this error

```
Error (10174): Verilog HDL Unsupported Feature error at Ram.sv(23): system function "$ceil" is not supported for synthesis
```

Is there a way around this so that I get the value calculated at compile time?
Using some different language construct instead of `parameter`?

Comment: This looks like a tool issue. Have you tried the latest version? This is a completely legal verilog and works on with other compilers.

Comment: Quartus Prime 18.0. I'm not a Verilog expert, but in my understanding there should be a way to make parameters calculations happen at compile time and it shouldn't be limited by what is synthesizable. But this is the way it is.

Comment: yes, parameters should be resolved at elaboration time.  One issue with this function is that it returns `real` value, which is not synthesizable. You can try to use `$rtoi($ceil(...))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up working around this with the following macro, this creates 2 extra parameters for the sake of rounding up, but this is the best solution I've found so far.
This is not limited to integer arguments and works with real numbers.
I've tested this with Quartus and Modelsim

```
`define Ceil(ParamName, Expression) \
 parameter ParamName``_F = Expression;\
 parameter integer ParamName``_R = ParamName``_F;\
 parameter integer ParamName = (ParamName``_R == ParamName``_F || ParamName``_R > ParamName``_F) ? ParamName``_R : (ParamName``_R + 1);
```

And then instead of

```
 parameter integer AUTOREFRESH_CLOCKS = $ceil(UTOREFRESH_NS/CLOCK_PERIOD_NS);
```

You would invoke the macro

```
`Ceil(AUTOREFRESH_CLOCKS, UTOREFRESH_NS/CLOCK_PERIOD_NS)
```

And this is not both synthesizable in Quartus and works in Modelsim

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

parameter integer PRECHARGE_CLOCKS = ((PRECHARGE_NS + CLOCK_PERIOD_NS -1) / CLOCK_PERIOD_NS);

It should round up as what $ceil does.

Comment: There's a caveat to this, it only works if both PRECHARGE_NS and CLOCK_PERIOD_NS are integers, if they are not and then you're converting to integer Modelsim applies regular rounding rules as far as I see, so e.g. (66+10-1)/10 becomes 8 and not 7 as desired